# How do I add a text in a specific location from within the script?

Tags: javascript, text

How do I add a text in a specific location Dynamically? I can do:

```
var txt = document.createTextNode("text")
```

But then I can't move it! I'm very sorry if this is a simple question but I'm **Extremely** new to JavaScript :-/

**EDIT** For example: What would you do if you had to add "This is a text" at the coordinates 450, 238 from inside the script?

Comment: Find the node you want to add it to, then use [`theParentNodeIwantToAddItTo.appendChild(txt)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Node.appendChild) (or similar as appropriate).

Comment: I'm sorry - But I don't know what you mean. :[

Comment: Consider searching for "HTML DOM tutorial" and reading some. After learning a little bit about how the DOM works, and how it can be manipulated from JavaScript, you will be able to formulate a better question about a specific issue. Now, note that the DOM and *layout* are only somewhat correlated; to position things with coordinates like that, see a "CSS tutorial" (you'll add the node, although it really should be an *Element* like a SPAN, and then set various CSS properties like the `display` and `top/left`).

Comment: http://css-tricks.com/absolute-positioning-inside-relative-positioning/ talks a bit about "absolute CSS positioning"

Answer (score 1):

It kind of depends on what your adding and where you are adding it. If you are adding text to an empty node for example then innerHtml is probably the easiest, fastest, and most performant way to do so.
`document.getElementById('container').innerHtml = 'text I want to insert'`

The caveat for this is that it will completely replace the contents of the container element with your text so you can't do this if you just want to add to the text.

Otherwise as pst said in the comment on your questions calling `document.getElementById('container').addChild(txtNode)` will add a new child to the container node.